# Coding style advantages in importing individual classes over importing by wildcard (star)

Tags: java, eclipse, import, ide, wildcard

Many Java classes involves importing from other packages, including those from built-in packages such as `java.awt` and `javax.swing` for GUI programming, or using the classes from other packages from the same Java project.

I currently use the Eclipse IDE, and imports are done whenever they are needed. However, when I use a method that requires importing from another package, it only imports the *relevant classes* from that package. That makes it more difficult for me to manually manage the imports, as well as making the imported packages harder to read. I almost always make my code more compact by using the wildcard character * instead, to indicate that I would import *all the classes* from that package.

Here is a simple Java program which creates a JFrame containing a white JPanel with a JLabel and JButton.

```
/* What I got */
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/* Can be instead */
// import java.awt.*;
// import java.swing.*;

public class GUIframe extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GUIframe() {
        super();

        this.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        this.setTitle("JFrame");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.add(new JLabel("JLabel"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Button"));

        this.getContentPane().add(panel);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I wonder what are the coding-style advantages of just importing individual classes from imported packages rather than importing all the classes through wildcard? (It is known that it generates the same bytecode, so no runtime performance difference and only minor compile-time difference)

As of now, I only choose wildcard import unless the number of class imports is very small, because it is easier to manage. **When is it appropriate to individually import, and when is it appropriate when importing by wildcard?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no runtime performance differences. It mainly stems down to being able to understand what was used.

You are right if you make use of, say 75% of the calls in a package it's probably best to import that entire package with wildcard. Whereas if you only make use of 1 or 2 out of 100 its easier to see what you're using.